# Accessing Media Library Photos and Videos on OS X Using Delphi

Tags: macos, delphi, video, photo, media-library

I am trying to develop a app for OS X El Capitan using Delphi 10 Seattle.

I tried using FMX.MediaLibrary but unfortunately it only works for IOS and Android as and not for OS X.
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.MediaLibrary.IFMXPhotoLibrary

How to access media Library pictures and videos on Mac OS X?

Comment: What are you looking for? An API to navigate all images on the machine? Or the path to the images folder? What facilities are available for the native Mac languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike on iOS or Android, there is no system media library API. Rather, even a 'sandboxed' Mac application has access to the user's general home directory like on Windows. As such, to prompt the user for a picture or video to open, just use TOpenDialog, and for a location to save to, TSaveDialog.

That said, if you are intending to create a sandboxed application, make sure you do use TOpenDialog/TSaveDialog (or their underlying Cocoa equivalents, NSOpenPanel and NSSavePanel). This is because the OS will only allow a sandboxed application to open or save to a file that it knows the user has explicitly asked the application to operate on.